# Howto access an already initialized class variable in main.py from another class

Tags: python, kivy

I have a class with a set of variables that is initialized and accessed from my main.py script. I have another class that is imported from a folder one level deep from the main.py file.

I can access the already set variables anywhere in my main.py file by referencing `appVars.some_variable`. However, I am not able to access them in the `--screen1.py` class. It seems the `--Variables.py` class is being reinitialized in the nested class which results in a blank value.

How do I access the already initialized class variable from the `main.py` script inside of my `--ScreenOne.py` script?

**File/Folder Structure**

```
main.py
-classes
--ScreenOne.py
--Variables.py
```

**variables.py**

```py
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Variables():
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_time = StringProperty('')
```

**main.py**

```py
from classes.ScreenOne import ScreenOne
from classes.Variables import Variables
appVars = Variables()

class SomeApp(App):

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        appVars.server_time = datetime.now()
```

**--ScreenOne.py**

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from classes.Variables import Variables

class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        print(Variables.server_time)
```

I have also tried adding `appVars = Variables()` to the beginning of the `--ScreenOne.py` script and referencing `appVars.server_time` however, it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In main.py you initiate class Variables by `appVars = Variables()`. But in `ScreenOne` you import Variables but never initiate it, besides initiating it will give a new instance not the same as appVars in main (also `print(Variables.server_time)` will give an error).

To use appVars in ScreenOne you will need to pass appVars to this class, like:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__(self, appVars):
        self.appVars = appVars

    def on_enter(self):
        print(self.appVars.server_time)
```

Then when you initiate `ScreenOne` you do something like:

```
screen_one = ScreenOne(appVars)
```

Note in `ScreenOne`, you do not need to import `Variables` as all attributes of this class will come with `appVars`.

By the way as per PEP8 variable names should not use capitals but underscore instead, `appVars` -> `app_vars`.